# ListThings AWS IoT with Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

```
def getthings():
   client = boto3.client('iot', region_name='name') 
   response = client.list_things(nextToken='string', maxResults=123, attributeName='string', attributeValue='string', thingTypeName='string')
```

I am a beginner in Python, I have the following code that I get from the AWS [documentation](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/iot.html#IoT.Client.list_things) to have the list of things in AWS IoT. I have the following error :

```
InvalidRequestException: An error occurred (InvalidRequestException)
```

when calling the ListThings operation.

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though there is not much details to this exception the following steps could  help resolve faster.

- You can try the with python console first.
- You need to make sure you have AWS-CLI installed
- Ensure you have AWS configure for configuring your access key and secret keys

By the way the following code worked to determine the list of things:

```
client=boto3.client('iot')
response = client.list_things(maxResults=123, thingTypeName='appropriate thing type')
```